# Should I learn Fourier Analysis or Complex Analysis first?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Are the two subjects highly interrelated?  Which draws more heavily from the other?  Which do you recommend I learn first?

Thank you.

Comment: I think this depends highly on your background and what applications you intend to pursue.

Comment: There are many relationships between the two subjects.  But you only really see them as you get deeper into both subjects.  So in my opinion it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

I have taken both Fourier Analysis and Complex Analysis.
And they are interrelated, but you won't see much overlap if this is the first introduction to these subjects.
And it depends on how the courses are structured, if they are done in an applied way or theoretical pure math way. 
Both Fourier Analysis and Complex Analysis have very good application to fields in Physics and Engineering. But Fourier Analysis is usually taught in a very applied way, while Complex Analysis is usually more theoretically taught, kind of closer to Real Analysis.
But Fourier Analysis is usually taught as part of Differential/Partial Differential Equations and in Engineering you learn it in a course usually called "Signals and Systems" or "Signal Analysis".

SO from this perspective the two subjects are different, in the Undergrad years.
SO like the other comment, it really doesn't matter which you take first.

BUT if you like more applied type of math, I would suggest Fourier Analysis, if you like
more theoretical math then take Complex Analysis.

Regards,

Palue